# RegOpenKey / RegOpenKeyEx returns 2 (file not found) on Windows 7, while key exists

Tags: c++, c, registry, registrykey

I am trying to read a value from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes on Windows 7 as a standard user, and although the key exists, I get an error. Both codes below don't success:

```
l = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Classes", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);

// RegOpenKeyEx doesn't success either
l = RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Classes", &hKey);
```

This code is located in a **dll** called by an application doing many things (I don't know all that it does).

However, a simple app with just **RegOpenKey** on the **same computer** with the **same account** works perfectly...

Can anyone tell me what could cause the problem and the differences between the two?
The test app is written in c++, while the dll is written in c.

**EDIT:** Problem solved, by just removing the "L" before L"Software\Classes"...

Comment: Is your OS 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @João Augusto: The question says "returns 2 (file not found)"

Comment: then since you say that your operating system is 32 bits there is only 1 option, the application that calls the dll is running under another user.

Comment: or impersonating another user.

Comment: I bet the issue is something else completely. For example, you may be calling `GetLastError` after calling `RegOpenKey` without first checking the return value of `RegOpenKey`.

Comment: That might be the way the two apps are compiled

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by passing "Software\Classes" instead of L"Software\Classes" to the function.

Comment: That makes no sense. You can't pass either `char*` or `wchar_t*`. It's one or the other. Are you using the right header files?!

Comment: Well I am not a C/C++ developper, I don't even know what that "L" means. The code was taken from a program written in C++, and it worked well, but in the Dll written in C, I had to remove the "L" to have it work...

Comment: I am calling my function like this (now): OverrideClassesRoot(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Classes"); Here is its protoype: OverrideClassesRoot(HKEY hKeyBase, LPCWSTR szOverrideKey) And I am calling RegOpenKey in the function this way: RegOpenKey(hKeyBase, szOverrideKey, &hKey)

Answer (score 2):

Likely, the code is running as a different user or its current user isn't in synch with the cached registry key for the process. See [RegOpenCurrentUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724894%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).